# The [random] tag is no more

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[image: this tag has been BURNINATED by TROGDOR]

---

Unless anyone has any objections or wants to salvage/synonym [random](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) somehow, I'm going to burninate it in a couple of days. *Randomness itself* doesn't seem like a useful area of expertise, and the tag isn't well-used.

It gets used beside [generator](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generator) and [encounter-tables](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-tables) a lot and in a couple of questions about dice rolls, but all of those things are implicitly about randomness anyway.

For historical record, [random](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) is attached to these 11 questions:

- [What ever happened to rolling for stats, encountering class trainers, etc?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47801/what-ever-happened-to-rolling-for-stats-encountering-class-trainers-etc)
- [Random Dungeon/Maze Generator](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/540/random-dungeon-maze-generator)
- [What's a good random dungeon generator for D&D 3.5?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/whats-a-good-random-dungeon-generator-for-dd-3-5)
- [Paper-and-dice random loot chart for psionic item powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45606/random-treasure-psionic-item-powers-chart)
- [How to randomly generate a village or town for old school D&D game?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/how-to-randomly-generate-a-village-or-town-for-old-school-dd-game)
- [What are some interesting ways to structure a random encounter table?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/365/what-are-some-interesting-ways-to-structure-a-random-encounter-table)
- [Rules for generating a game world as you go?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14706/rules-for-generating-a-game-world-as-you-go)
- [Weapon that does 5 damage vs. one that does 1d10 damage: What characteristic of the weapons causes this difference?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8512/weapon-that-does-5-damage-vs-one-that-does-1d10-damage-what-characteristic-of)
- [Is there a working online random adventure generator for D&D 3.5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6351/is-there-a-working-online-random-adventure-generator-for-dnd-3-5e)
- [Does anyone have random encounter tables for 4th edition D&D?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/741/does-anyone-have-random-encounter-tables-for-4th-edition-dd)
- [Is there a random encounter generator online, for color/minor city detail stuff?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/is-there-a-random-encounter-generator-online-for-color-minor-city-detail-stuff)

Comment: Sounds like a damn fine idea to me

Comment: It doesn't have a description. No wonder it'll be used incorrectly.

Comment: @Joninean I'm not sure we have a useful 'correct' usage for this.

Comment: Burn it, with fire.

Comment: Trogdor! Trogdor!

Comment: I would probably suggest that in the wake of removing the tag, maybe add the "random" factor to the tag wiki? Especially since [tag:encounter-tables] doesn't even have one.

Comment: Burninating the taaags, he was a maaan... I mean he was a dragon man